# Javascript variables in shopify product.liquid file

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm loading javascript variables in the product.liquid file on shopify.I'm also loading an external javascript file as well. This javascript file is using the variables that i put in the liquid file. Seems like the variables are undefined in the external JS file eventhough i gave them values

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you render Liquid, you can populate JS variables. The thing is, you need to wait for the DOM to be downloaded and for all the rendered code to be delivered to the browser before you try and use it or access it. Ensure you are waiting properly before trying to access your variables.

In a common JS library like jQuery, you can use this block to wrap your code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // stuff
});
```